# How can I achieve z-index effect on children of horizontally scrolling flex container on hover?

Tags: overflow, z-index, horizontal-scrolling

I'm currently working on a layout where I have a horizontally scrolling flex container. The container has children, and on hover, I want the children to appear above the container's content. I've tried various approaches, including setting z-index, but the children still appear under the content during hover. Any suggestions or solutions for achieving the desired z-index effect on hover within a flex layout would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!